# Is there any equivalent of oracle ref cursor in MS Access?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, ms-access, ref-cursor

We are looking for Oracle Ref Cursor alternative in MS Access database as we have small data.We want to go light but before jumping into MS Access just wanted to evaluate the features it has to offer.I am no MS-Access developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access has no classical cursors that can be defined in SQL. Access SQL is too limited.

But, a close analog of a cursor is DAO (Data Access Objects) under VBA. Using code, you can emulate most anything a Ref-Cursor can do.

Overview DAO vs. Ref-Cursor

- May be dynamically opened or opened based on logic.   DAO = Yes; Ref-Cursor = Yes
- Can be returned to a client (calling program). DAO = Yes; Ref-Cursor = Yes
- Can be global. DAO = Yes; Ref-Cursor = NO
- Can be passed from subroutine to subroutine. DAO = Yes; Ref-Cursor = Yes

(Credit to [Oracle PL/SQL REF Cursors](http://sql-plsql.blogspot.com/2007/05/oracle-plsql-ref-cursors.html))

Comment: Thank you Kismert for such a wonderful answer! It really helped us to navigate through the decision. Now I have another question in my head that Like Oracle has output parameter, do we have anything equivalent to it in MS-Access?

Comment: I would start a new question.

If by output, you mean a return value from a store procedure? Since Access uses VBA as the programming language, then you not really calling store procedures, but in fact calling VBA code, and such code can certainly return values to the calling code. It really comes down to the context of when and how and where you are calling such code. And usually even more important is what you plan to do with the returned value.

Comment: In general, if you have a server-side stored procedure in Oracle, the equivalent would be a 'client-side VBA/DAO function' in Access.